# Is there any way to run both wifi and ethernet at same time in android Programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to connect the unifier printer through and communicate with the unifier on Ethernet and communicate with server APIs with wifi at the same time. But whenever I enable my Ethernet connection it disables the Wi-Fi automatically. I don't need internet access on Ethernet just using it to Communicate with unifier.

**it there any way to do this. That my unifier communicates through ethernet and wifi is working for other apps at the same time?**

Comment: please show us some code snippet, what have you tried?

Comment: @keshav there is no code snippet, actually when I connect the ethernet cable to my android device with ethernet settings, the wifi interface automatically turned off. 
Trying to find solution for this.